# Error when clicking on a category in admin (related to SEOMatic?)

Tags: categories, plugin-seomatic, seomatic

I get the atatched error when clicking in the admin of my site - it seems to be related to SEO Matic but not sure?

Anybody any idea?

Many thanks
Malcolm

[image]

Comment: Try disabling Seomatic to see if it gets rid of the error. If yes, check your Seomatic settings regarding the SEO Category and/or contact the plugin developer regarding the bug/error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug fixed in Craft CMS 3.7.13 (I believe it was introduced in 3.7.11) (though I should have been doing better error checking myself... which I fixed in SEOmatic too).

ref: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#3713---2021-09-14

Comment: Thanks Andrew, much appreciated